# sum of reciprocal of n natural numbers in python

Tags: python

```
n = int(input("Enter n:"))
s = 0.0
for i in range (1,n+1):
     s = s+1.0/(i*i)
print(s)
```

**answer**

```
Enter n:10
1.5497677311665408
```

IS THERE ANY WAY TO FIND BIT MORE EASIER THAN THIS

Comment: Why have you used ```(i*i)```?

Comment: `sum(1.0 / (i * i) for i in range(1, n+1))` more or less does the same thing, but only takes one line.  And again, it's unclear whether you're adding the sum of the reciprocal (your title) or the sum of the square of the reciprocal (your code).

Comment: i code the sum of reciprocal of n natural numbers not the squares

Comment: @shemayonsoloman For large ```n```, you can get a good approximation without any loops

Answer (score 0):

For better performance and readability, `numpy` may be a good choice:

```
import numpy as np
(1 / np.arange(1, n+1)**2).sum() 
# or (1 / np.arange(1, n+1)).sum() ?
#1.5497677311665408
```

Comment: n is not defined here

Comment: You defined it in your example.